# Having a difficult time resolving "TypeError: 'list' object is not callable" issue

Tags: python, python-3.x

Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/root/PycharmProjects/Capstone2/**main**", line 207, in 
>       for paramIndex in range(0, 4): TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/root/PycharmProjects/Capstone2/**main**", line 249, in 
>       print('stream ending')   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 758, in
>   **exit**
>       self.close()   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 737, in
>   close
>       self.stop_recording(splitter_port=port)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 1198, in
>   stop_recording
>       encoder.close()   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/encoders.py", line 431, in
>   close
>       self.stop()   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/encoders.py", line 815, in
>   stop
>       super(PiVideoEncoder, self).stop()   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/encoders.py", line 419, in
>   stop
>       self._close_output()   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/encoders.py", line 349, in
>   _close_output
>       mo.close_stream(output, opened)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/mmalobj.py", line 371, in
>   close_stream
>       stream.flush() ValueError: flush of closed file

Relevant Code:

```
angle = []
distance = []
speed = []
current = []
timestamp = []
parameterList = []
parameterList.extend((angle, distance, speed, current, timestamp))                

            for paramIndex in range(0, 4): # LINE 207
                # Select Range
                range = getRange(index, paramIndex + 5)
                cell_list = sheet.range(range[0], range[1], range[2], range[3])

                cellIndex = 0

                for cell in cell_list:
                    try:
                        cell.value = parameterList[paramIndex][cellIndex]
                    except:
                        print("PI: " + str(paramIndex))
                        print("CI: " + str(cellIndex))
                        print("PL LEN: " + str(len(parameterList)))
                        print("P LEN: " + str(len(parameterList[paramIndex])))
```

My Thoughts:

The error makes me think that paramIndex is a list and not an integer but the code executes fine for the first four iterations. This makes me think that there is something wrong with my last list (timestamp). The only thing that I can imagine being wrong with my last list is some sort of index out of bounds issue but...
The except block is never hit
The largest value cellIndex reaches is 30 (expected)
The length of parameterList is 5 (expected)
The length of timestamp is 31 (expected)

I am stumped. If anyone can offer some help that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is getRange user defined ?

Comment: Yes it is. Good point, I didn't think to check it since when I tested it earlier it appeared to be working fine. Full code can be seen here: https://github.com/AdamVen/Capstone/blob/master/__main__

Comment: You cannot use `range` as a variable name as it is a built-in.. This could be causing conflicts seeing as you reference it quite a lot!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

paramIndex is fine but you need to avoid calling variables the same name as your functions.  In this case, range() is a standard python function but you create a variable called 'range'.  Thereafter if you tried to use the range function you'd get an 'object is not callable' error because it's trying to use your range object as the standard range function.

If you insist on wanting to keep the range object name then use xrange() instead of range() where you define your for loop and you shouldn't get any conflicts.

Comment: It's such an obvious mistake in hindsight but I spent like two hours trying to figure out where I was going wrong. Thanks so much for the catch! Do you know why the error was only occurring in later iterations of the loop?

Comment: Most python-aware IDE's will underline redefinitions of built-in variables. It won't save you from redefining your own variables or issues with scope, but would have prevented this problem. You should check out PyCharm.

Comment: I am actually using PyCharm! When I get back into school tomorrow I'll see if I was ignoring any underlines or did anything to disable them.